# how to apply macro on list of lines with vim

Tags: linux, vim, macros

let's suppose I want to apply a macro stored on register 1 on lines: 2, 5, 9 but without applying on lines in between. I saw that you can give a range but that is not what I want.
I've tried some variation on :2, 5, 9 @1 without success

Comment: on a side note, you can use a regex to select lines which the macro will apply, which is pretty cool. But still, I have to make sure my regex does select the appropriate lines, in a lot of cases, just writting the lines number would be faster...

Comment: It would be worth noting that the numbered registers change often so you may wan to use a lowercase letter register. e.g. `"q`. See `:h quote1` for more information

Comment: thanks for the note, indeed numbered registers was a bad choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those lines have something in common, you can use the `:global` and `:normal` commands:

```
:g/foo/norm! @1
```

which is slightly "smarter" but probably a bit less intuitive than:

```
2G@1
5G@1
9G@1
```

See `:help :global` and `:help :normal`.

Comment: yes, as I said in my comment, the problem is to make sure the regex doesn't has undesirable side effect, you spend some time "testing" it. And when I just have a couples of lines it would be quicker and less error prone to just list the lines number...
but it this close of what I'm looking for

Comment: If you have agile fingers and don't mind a bit of very simple vim scripting, you can use something like `:for l in [2,5,9]|exe l"norm @1"|endfo`.

Comment: well it does work! I was hoping for something more concise but this is good enough! thanks